# Usage of "derweilen"

Tags: difference, usage

Can I use *derweilen* instead of *während*? Is it more formal than *während*?

> 1. Ich fegte den Fußboden, derweilen ich fernsah.
> 2. Ich fegte den Fußboden, während ich fernsah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"derweil" is oldfashioned and "derweilen" is extremely oldfashioned. I'd recommend you to use "während".

[duden.de/rechtschreibung/derweil_Konjunktion](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/derweil_Konjunktion)

Comment: It depends a bit. I feel it is not that old fashioned in Thüringen and Sachsen like elsewhere.